# SQL order groups by group subtotal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this:

```
SaleID    ParentCo    Subsidiary      Amount
1         BigCo       Big A LTD       10
2         MedCo       Medium Inc.     10
3         BigCo       BigCo Corp.     10
4         BigCo       Biggest Co.     10
5         BigCo       Big A LTD       10
6         MedCo       Medium LLC      10
7         MedCo       Medium Inc.     10
8         SmallCo     SmallCo         10
```

I would like to display totals for each ParentCo and each Subsidiary, ordered DESC by ParentCo and nestedly (is that a word?) grouped and ordered by Subsidiary, like this:

```
ParentCo     Subsidiary    SumOfAmount
BigCo        (all)         40
BigCo        Big A LTD     20
BigCo        BigCo Corp    10
BigCo        Biggest Co.   10
MedCo        (all)         30
MedCo        Medium Inc.   20
MedCo        Medium LLC    10
SmallCo      (all)         10
SmallCo      SmallCo       10
```

The farthest I have gotten is this:

```
SELECT [ParentCo], [Subsidiary], SUM([Amount]) AS SumOfAmount FROM [table]
GROUP BY [ParentCo], [Subsidiary]
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY SumOfAmount DESC;
```

But as anybody who knows anything will see, that doesn't work because it displays all rows descending by SumOfAmount, without keeping the totals for each subsidiary aligned below (or for that matter, above or next to) the total for its ParentCo.

I am thinking I probably need some kind of nested query, but then, I am a noob and the above is the most complex SQL I have ever written.

In case it is easier, it would work just as well for me to display the sums for subsidiaries and parents in separate columns, repeating the parent's sum next to each subsidiary:

```
ParentCo     Subsidiary    SumOfSubsidiary   SumOfParent
BigCo        Big A LTD     20                40
BigCo        BigCo Corp    10                40
BigCo        Biggest Co.   10                40
MedCo        Medium Inc.   20                30
MedCo        Medium LLC    10                30
SmallCo      SmallCo       10                10
```

And while we are at it, a related question:

Is there a way to display only the total for each ParentCo, but next to it, the name and subtotal for its *subsidiary with the largest subtotal*, like this:

```
ParentCo     SumOfParent    LargestSubsidiary  SumOfSubsidiary  
BigCo        40             Big A LTD          20
MedCo        30             Medium Inc.        20
SmallCo      10             SmallCo            10
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` coupled with `SUM OVER()` to achieve the desired sorting:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(ParentCo, 'ALL') AS ParentCo,
        ISNULL(Subsidiary, 'ALL') AS Subsidiary,
        SUM(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY 
        ParentCo, Subsidiary
    WITH ROLLUP
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        sm = SUM(SumOfAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentCo)
    FROM Cte
    WHERE
        ParentCo <> 'ALL'
)
SELECT
    ParentCo, Subsidiary, SumOfAmount
FROM CteFinal
ORDER BY
    sm DESC, SumOfAmount DESC
```

---

For your second question, you can simply use `SUM OVER()`:

```
SELECT *,
    SumOfAmount = SUM(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentCo)
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Second question was probably the better question for my purposes. Short and sweet, works great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get your first result set you could also use this query:

```
SELECT 
    ParentCo, 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(Subsiduary) = 1 THEN '(all)' ELSE Subsiduary END AS Subsiduary, 
    SUM(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM 
    [table]
GROUP BY 
    ParentCo, 
    ROLLUP(Subsiduary)
ORDER BY 
    ParentCo, 
    Subsiduary
```